# Proof by induction of a specific series

Tags: discrete-mathematics

> $$2\times6\times10\times14\times\cdots\times(4n-2) = \frac{(2n)!}{n!}$$

My solution: I proved base case with both sides being $2$ if $n=1$; also assumed that series is true for $k$.

Now my inductive step is as follows:

$$\begin{align}
2\times6\times10\times14\dots (4k-2)\times (4(k+1) -2) &= \frac{(2k)!}{k!}(4(k+1)-2)\\[5pt]
&= \frac{2(2k+1)(2k)!}{k!}\\[5pt]
&= \frac{2(2k+1)!}{k!}
\end{align}$$

This is where I'm stuck, how do I go from here to $\dfrac{(2k+2)!}{(k+1)!}$? I know the last step is wrong.

Comment: Multiply denominator and numerator by $k+1$ and then you can use $2(k+1)=2k+2$ to get $(2k+2)!$

Comment: Wow I feel really stupid, thank you so much. I did multiply k+1 above and below but didn't go any further!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the inductive step you have
$$
2\times4\times6\times\cdots\times(4(k+1)-2)=2\times4\times6\times\cdots\times(4k-2)\times(4(k+1)-2)\\ \ \\=\frac{(2k)!(4(k+1)-2)}{k!}
=\frac{(2k)!(4k+2)}{k!}
=\frac{2(2k)!(2k+1)}{k!}
=\frac{2(2k+1)!}{k!}
=\frac{2(2k+2)!}{k!(2k+2)}
=\frac{(2k+2)!}{k!(k+1)}
=\frac{(2k+2)!}{(k+1)!}
$$